# Count number of observations without N/A per year in R

Tags: r, count, dplyr, missing-data

I have a dataset and I want to summarize the number of observations without the missing values (denoted by NA).

My data is similar as the following:

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
               text="CompanyNumber ResponseVariable Year ExplanatoryVariable1 ExplanatoryVariable2
               1 2.5 2000 1 2
               1 4 2001 3 1
               1 3 2002 NA 7
               2 1 2000 3 NA
               2 2.4 2001 0 4
               2 6 2002 2 9
               3 10 2000 NA 3")
```

I was planning to use the package dplyr, but that does only take the years into account and not the different variables:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(number = n())
```

How can I obtain the following outcome?

```
                    2000 2001 2002
ExplanatoryVariable1  2   2    1 
ExplanatoryVariable2  2   2    2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the counts, you can start by using:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Expla")), ~sum(!is.na(.)))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Year ExplanatoryVariable1 ExplanatoryVariable2
#  <int>                <int>                <int>
#1  2000                    2                    2
#2  2001                    2                    2
#3  2002                    1                    2
```

If you want to reshape it as shown in your question, you can extend the pipe using tidyr functions:

```
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Expla")), ~sum(!is.na(.))) %>% 
  gather(var, count, -Year) %>% 
  spread(Year, count)
## A tibble: 2 x 4
#                   var `2000` `2001` `2002`
#*                <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 ExplanatoryVariable1      2      2      1
#2 ExplanatoryVariable2      2      2      2
```

---

Just to let OP know, since they have ~200 explanatory variables to select. You can use another option of `summarise_at` to select the variables. You can simply name the first:last variable, if they are ordered correctly in the data, for example:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(ExplanatoryVariable1:ExplanatoryVariable2), ~sum(!is.na(.)))
```

Or:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise_at(3:4, ~sum(!is.na(.)))
```

Or store the variable names in a vector and use that:

```
vars <- names(data)[4:5]
data %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars, ~sum(!is.na(.)))
```

Comment: Thanks, the only thing is that in my real data not all my explanatory variables have a name that begins with the characters "Expla".

Comment: @Tox, well then you either have to tell me what are their names or I can only assume something like _all_ columns except year are explanatory variables. Or is there some kind of pattern in the names?

Comment: Yes, I have around 200 variables, so calling them by name is not ideal. I probably need to extract the names of the explanatory variables and call them back by names(explanatoryVariables). I will have a look how I can solve this and let you know in case that I solved this, thanks so far!

Comment: @Tox, I added another option to select multiple variables

Answer (score 4):

```
data %>%
  gather(cat, val, -(1:3)) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  group_by(Year, cat) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  spread(Year, n)

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#                    cat `2000` `2001` `2002`
# *                <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1 ExplanatoryVariable1      2      2      1
# 2 ExplanatoryVariable2      2      2      2
```

Should do it. You start by making the data stacked, and the simply calculating the n for both year and each explanatory variable. If you want the data back to wide format, then use `spread`, but either way without `spread`, you get the counts for both variables.

Answer (score 4):

Using base R:

```
  do.call(cbind,by(data[3:5], data$Year,function(x) colSums(!is.na(x[-1]))))                       
                      2000 2001 2002
 ExplanatoryVariable1    2    2    1
 ExplanatoryVariable2    2    2    2
```

For aggregate:

```
 aggregate(.~Year,data[3:5],function(x) sum(!is.na(x)),na.action = function(x)x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `aggregate` in base R.

```
aggregate(list(ExplanatoryVariable1 = data$ExplanatoryVariable1,
               ExplanatoryVariable2 = data$ExplanatoryVariable2),
          list(Year = data$Year),
          function(x) length(x[!is.na(x)]))
#  Year ExplanatoryVariable1 ExplanatoryVariable2
#1 2000                    2                    2
#2 2001                    2                    2
#3 2002                    1                    2
```